# Change div size dynamically based on background-image aspect ratio and fixed height

Tags: javascript, css, slider, aspect-ratio, slick.js

I am using slick slider (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to show images of various sizes (both portrait and landscape pictures). The image is shown as a background-image property of the div

However, the slider has a fixed width/height out of the box.

My requirement is to have all the slick divs with a fixed height - but a variable width based on the portrait or landscape picture. In the below code, images 2,3 are portrait mode and 1,4 are landscape mode.

```
      <div class="wrapper gallery-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid gallery-container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 slideshow">
          <div class="agent-detail-slideshow" id="agent-detail-slideshow">
            <div class="item slick-slide-width" data-image="assets/img/1.png" style="background-image:url('assets/img/1.png')"></div>
            <div class="item slick-slide-width" data-image="assets/img/2.png" style="background-image:url('assets/img/2.png')"></div>

            <div class="item slick-slide-width" data-image="assets/img/3.png" style="background-image:url('assets/img/3.png')"></div>
            <div class="item slick-slide-width" data-image="assets/img/4.png" style="background-image:url('assets/img/4.png')"></div>
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li class="next-carat white shadow"></li>
            <li class="prev-carat white shadow"></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I set the variable width property of the slider to true and have added a custom slick-slide-width class to each div.

What CSS needs to go into the slick-slide-width ?

Is it possible to use just CSS to adjust the div width or do I need any javascript to control the div width. Also, the height needs to be fixed and as decided by the slider (responsively). So, it would be landscape,portrait,portrait,landscape divs in the above code.

Comment: In order to help the community to reproduce your case, can you provide a working example inside a snippet instead of a code block? Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How would we know which image is portrait or which is landscape?

Answer (score 1):

To size your slides based on image ratio you need to use proper `<img />` tags in your slides (mind the markup in the example below). And use...

```js
$('...').slick({
  // ...
  variableWidth: true
  centerMode: true, // optional
  // ...
});
```

If your images do not already have the same height, you probably want to couple this with...

```
.slick-slide img { max-height: /*...*/ }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#agent-detail-slideshow').slick({
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    centerMode: true,
    variableWidth: true
  });
})
```

```css
.slick-slide {
  opacity: .1;
  transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.4, 0, .2, 1);
  outline: none;
}

.slick-current {
  opacity: 1;
}
.slideshow {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>


<div class="wrapper gallery-wrapper">
  <div class="container gallery-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 slideshow">
        <div class="agent-detail-slideshow" id="agent-detail-slideshow">
          <div class="item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/600/300" /></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/800/300" /></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/400/300" /></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300" /></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/500/300" /></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked great by adding the img tags inside the divs. Which part of the code actually causes the div to adjust based on the image size?

Comment: @user972391, the `<img />` part. It's read as "content". The slider makes them all have equal `height`s (unless you set `adaptiveHeight: true` in slick options - which you shouldn't). The `width` of each slide is calculated proportionally, based on image ratio. If you use apply images as `background-image`, the ratio of each slide is taken from slider and the it's applied to fit, depending on `background` properties (`size`, `repeat`...).

Comment: Thanks @Andrei for the explanation